# When is an AR model appropriate for a data set?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

What criteria does the data set need to satisfy so we can evaluate whether it is appropriate for an AR model? I have found a structural break for the data set (US inflation), which is a violation of stationary.

Comment: You can adjust for the structural break and then use the AR model for the adjusted data (you can adjust within an AR model, too).

Comment: @RichardHardy In particular, my first thought is that you could include an exogenous indicator variable that's 0 before the break and 1 after the break. Is that reasonable?

Comment: @Wayne, yes, I suppose so.

Comment: If this is an assignment (which you mention it is in the comments under the answer), then consider adding the [tag:self-study] tag and reading its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structural break is a symptom ... the cause may be a shift in the mean or trend or a shift in any other parameter or number of parameters. The cause may be due to a deterministic change in the error variance or an untreated dependency of the expected value and the error variance. Simple procedures that just test for a mean change are often (nearly always !) suspect as the suggested remedy may be flawed.

In specific an AR model is appropriate when the coefficients are statistically significant and the error process is free of any non-random structure.

Comment: Can I find the coefficient between the inflation rates and GDP data?

Comment: To do that one would need to form a ARMAX model where both memory and X are allowed to be included. If you wish to post your data I will try and be more specific.

Comment: I am not sure if I am allowed to do that, as it is a part of an assignment. Is there any way I could assist you helping me? Thanks

Comment: ok .. if you want you can contact me directly and I will briefly try to help you although I would prefer continuing the dialogue here so that others can learn/read

Comment: How would I contact you directly? Of course, having the conversation here would be a great help for others as well. I appreciate the help by the way!

Comment: you can get my contact info from my profile

Comment: If you think my answer was helpful ( and the best) please accept it and close the question